# find value in ArrayList<HashMap> and get the index

Tags: java, android

I have a `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` and it looks something like this

```
 [{code=123, name=tester, model=car1},{code=456, name=tester, model=car2},{code=789, name=tester, model=car3}]
```

And what I want to do is search through it to find if any model number equals car2 and get the index of the object (in this case 1) so i can print out the name. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scan each element in your list and `break` when you've found your element.

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < haystackList.size(); i++){
  if(haystackList.get(i).get("model").equals(needle)){
    // Break
  }
}

if(i == haystackList.size()){
// Failure
} else {
// Success
}
```

Comment: I think this gets me on the right track, I will try it and see if it works

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an efficient solution, as it can end up going through the entire ArrayList twice, but it'll get the job done.

```
int index;
for( HashMap m : mapList )
{
    if( m.get( "model" ).equals( "car2" ) )
    {
        index = arrayList.indexOf( m );
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the ArrayList and check each HashMap:

```
for (HashMap map : arraylist) {
    if ("car2".equals(map.get("model"))) {
        System.out.println("index: " + arraylist.indexOf(map));
        System.out.println("name: " + map.get("name"));
        break;
    }
}
```

The break was included under the assumption that only one model will be car2.